# I need to extract data from a webpage which is within a script tag using python

Tags: python

The String I have contains

```
<script type="text/javascript">!function(e){var t={};function n(o){if(t[o])return t[o].exports;var r=t[o]={i:o,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[o].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,n),r.l=!0,r.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,o){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:o})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var o=Object.create(null);if(n.r(o),Object.defineProperty(o,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var r in e)n.d(o,r,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,r));return o},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=1461)}({1461:function(e,t,n){"use strict";window.OOKLA=window.OOKLA||{},window.OOKLA.INIT_DATA={"result":{"date":1174430405,"id":"102041099","download":160,"upload":1071,"latency":181,"distance":1100,"country_code":"MX","server_id":292,"server_name":"Atlanta, GA","sponsor_name":"One Ring Networks","sponsor_url":null,"connection_mode":"multi","isp_name":"Universidad Autonoma de Nuevo Leon","isp_rating":"3.5","test_rank":28,"test_grade":"D","test_rating":2,"additional_servers":[],"path":"result\u002F102041099","hasSecondary":false}},window.OOKLA.globals={"year":2021,"jsPaths":{"bundle":"\u002Fjavascript\u002Fspeedtest-main.js?v=493de14e3a08befbca036fbced72e697","bundle.map":"\u002Fjavascript\u002Fspeedtest-main.js.map?v=696e4652af79d58806aae60ed92c9ba3"},"cdnUrl":"\u002F\u002Fb.cdnst.net","bundleUrl":"\u002F\u002Fb.cdnst.net","hostSubdomain":"","configs":{"clientConfigOverride":{},"linkToSt3":false,"ads":true,"lifetimeSubscriptionDate":"2199-01-01 00:00:00","subscriptions":[],"payments":{"client":{"apiKey":"pk_live_KTgd89Iyw9JidRcjj41PBFAD007uzOUJpb","input_style":{"base":{"color":"#ffffff","lineHeight":"24px","fontSize":"16px","::placeholder":{"color":"#aab7c4"}},"invalid":{"color":"#ff3366","iconColor":"#ff3366"}}}},
```

I want to extract only

```
"date":1174430405,"id":"102041099","download":160,"upload":1071,"latency":181,"distance":1100,"country_code":"MX","server_id":292,"server_name":"Atlanta, GA","sponsor_name":"One Ring Networks","sponsor_url":null,"connection_mode":"multi","isp_name":"Universidad Autonoma de Nuevo Leon","isp_rating":"3.5","test_rank":28,"test_grade":"D","test_rating":2,"additional_servers":[],"path":"result\u002F102041099","hasSecondary":false
```

How is this possible with Python? I tried with `re` and have been struggling for 2 days.

Comment: you need to use `requests` library to download Actual HTML and then you need to use `beautifulsoup` library to extract data from the html.

Comment: I have used beautifulsoup to get the request into a soup object. I am having trouble extracting that particular part of the object.

Comment: show us what you already tried maybe it's dynamic HTML that why you can't access to that particular Tag instead you can use `selenium`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
string = '<script type="text/javascript">!function(e){var t={};function n(o){if(t[o])return t[o].exports;var r=t[o]={i:o,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[o].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,n),r.l=!0,r.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,o){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:o})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var o=Object.create(null);if(n.r(o),Object.defineProperty(o,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var r in e)n.d(o,r,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,r));return o},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=1461)}({1461:function(e,t,n){"use strict";window.OOKLA=window.OOKLA||{},window.OOKLA.INIT_DATA={"result":{"date":1174430405,"id":"102041099","download":160,"upload":1071,"latency":181,"distance":1100,"country_code":"MX","server_id":292,"server_name":"Atlanta, GA","sponsor_name":"One Ring Networks","sponsor_url":null,"connection_mode":"multi","isp_name":"Universidad Autonoma de Nuevo Leon","isp_rating":"3.5","test_rank":28,"test_grade":"D","test_rating":2,"additional_servers":[],"path":"result\u002F102041099","hasSecondary":false}},window.OOKLA.globals={"year":2021,"jsPaths":{"bundle":"\u002Fjavascript\u002Fspeedtest-main.js?v=493de14e3a08befbca036fbced72e697","bundle.map":"\u002Fjavascript\u002Fspeedtest-main.js.map?v=696e4652af79d58806aae60ed92c9ba3"},"cdnUrl":"\u002F\u002Fb.cdnst.net","bundleUrl":"\u002F\u002Fb.cdnst.net","hostSubdomain":"","configs":{"clientConfigOverride":{},"linkToSt3":false,"ads":true,"lifetimeSubscriptionDate":"2199-01-01 00:00:00","subscriptions":[],"payments":{"client":{"apiKey":"pk_live_KTgd89Iyw9JidRcjj41PBFAD007uzOUJpb","input_style":{"base":{"color":"#ffffff","lineHeight":"24px","fontSize":"16px","::placeholder":{"color":"#aab7c4"}},"invalid":{"color":"#ff3366","iconColor":"#ff3366"}}}},'
string = string.split('"result":')[1]
string = string.split('}')[0]
string = string.replace('{','')
print(string)
```

output:

```
"date":1174430405,"id":"102041099","download":160,"upload":1071,"latency":181,"distance":1100,"country_code":"MX","server_id":292,"server_name":"Atlanta, GA","sponsor_name":"One Ring Networks","sponsor_url":null,"connection_mode":"multi","isp_name":"Universidad Autonoma de Nuevo Leon","isp_rating":"3.5","test_rank":28,"test_grade":"D","test_rating":2,"additional_servers":[],"path":"result/102041099","hasSecondary":false
```